# UriBuilder - remove port

Tags: c#

I want to build a Uri based off some string values, but I'd like to avoid showing the port when I call `.ToString()`.

```cs
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://www.google.co.uk/")
{
    Path = "test"
};
```

The below code outputs `http://www.google.co.uk:80/test` instead of `http://www.google.co.uk/test`. Is there a way to not include the port in the final string or do I have to use one of the workarounds (such as `new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), relativePath)` instead?

Comment: The documentation suggests that if you're not setting the port then it shouldn't show up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_UriBuilder_ToString

Comment: It indeed doesn't show up if I explicitly tell it that the `Port = -1`, but in any other case, it defaults to 80.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To achieve the result that you require you can just do like this.

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder()
{
    Scheme = "http",
    Host = "www.google.co.uk",
    Path = "test"
};

Uri uri = uriBuilder.Uri;
```

In the uri you will have the 'http://www.google.co.uk/test' result that you want.

If you check on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_UriBuilder__ctor_System_String_) you can see that

> This constructor initializes a new instance of the UriBuilder class with the Fragment, Host, Path, Port, Query, Scheme, and Uri properties set as specified in uri.
>   **If uri does not specify a scheme, the scheme defaults to "http:**".

Answer (score 6):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), set the `Port` to -1 and it will not print.

```cs
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://www.google.co.uk/")
{
    Path = "test",
    Port = -1
};
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to remove the port manually. Just call `uriBuilder.Uri.ToString()` instead of `uriBuilder.ToString()`.

This will correctly remove the port if the `uriBuilder.Uri.IsDefaultPort` property would return `true` and is a better way to print the URI correctly for all schemes.

Example:

```cs
new UriBuilder("http://www.google.co.uk/")
{
    Path = "test"
}.Uri.ToString()
```

This outputs `http://www.google.co.uk/test`

Comment: This answer needs an asterisk attached to it. `$Uri.Uri.ToString()` returns an unescaped version of the URL. If you're displaying the URL to the user this might be fine but if your intention is to provide them with a URL they can browse to this is not the way to go. Contrast this with `$Uri.Uri.AbsoluteUri` using a URL containing spaces, commas, etc, and it's unusable.